# How to style an individual WordPress menu item?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, styles

I'm trying to style only ONE menu item on my website. I have a "contact us" menu item on my WordPress website that I'm trying to change to color `#FF860C`.

I just tried this but no go:

```
li#menu-item-155.menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-155 {
  color:#FF860C;
}
```

I've also tried just using the ID without everything else but with no go. I know there's something I'm missing here. Possible adding an `a` somewhere to the style? It still doesn't make sense though for it to not work if I have the individual ID which is what is confusing.

The item I'm trying to change the color is the "contact us" option on my WordPress menu, you can see it at http://www.SimonSaysWebsites.com/

Comment: yes the contact simon, sorry

Comment: Copy and paste the actual html you have for Contact Simon

Comment: you can look at the source code using firebug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#menu-item-155 a{
  color: #FF860C;
}
```

seems to work (apply the color on the link inside)

Comment: awesome man!! it worked. very cool. thanks!!!! ill accept your answer once it lets me